# Finding the rows that are not common in two tables in oracle

Tags: oracle

I have two tables with following values.

```
tab1              tab2
----              ----
A                   A
B                   E
C                   F
D                   G
```

Output should be as follows:

```
O/P
---
B
C
D
E
F
G
```

Comment: The question seems clear to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
select field from tab1
union all
select field from tab2

minus

(select field from tab1
 intersect
 select field from tab2
);
```

OR :)

```
select field from tab1
minus
select field from tab2

union all

select field from tab2
minus
select field from tab1
```

But, BEST(for performance :) ) :

```
select distinct nvl(a.field, b.field) as field
from tab1 a
full join tab2 b on (a.field=b.field)
where a.field is null or b.field is null;
```

See here a [test](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/11435) for the above query.

Comment: The last query wont work for this case.it will display only the common values from both tables

Comment: I've added an sqlfiddle to show that is otherwise. It displays the non common records.

Answer (score 1):

```
select field from tab1 where field not in (select field from tab2) 
union 
select field from tab2 where field not in (select field from tab1)
```

Comment: It will work but in operator will have impact on performance.